# Send a file and parameters to a OpenFaas Dockerfile function

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, openfaas

I have a ffmpeg Dockerfile function that I deploy to my OpenFaaS:

```
FROM ghcr.io/openfaas/classic-watchdog:0.1.5 as watchdog

FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg:4.1-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

COPY --from=watchdog /fwatchdog /usr/bin/fwatchdog
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/fwatchdog

# Add non root user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser app -S -G app
RUN chown app /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

USER app

# Populate example here - i.e. "cat", "sha512sum" or "node index.js"
ENV fprocess="ffmpeg"
# Set to true to see request in function logs
ENV write_debug="false"

EXPOSE 8080

HEALTHCHECK --interval=3s CMD [ -e /tmp/.lock ] || exit 1

CMD ["fwatchdog"]
```

But I cannot figure out how I would be able to stream a file to the function and give parameters, so that ffmpeg knows about the file and parameter.
I am fairly new to OpenFaaS and maybe this is trivial, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can find your answer [here](https://github.com/alexellis/openfaas-streaming-templates)
To summarize:

- Create a template similar to alexellis's [bash-streaming](https://github.com/alexellis/openfaas-streaming-templates/tree/master/template/bash-streaming) replace that Dockerfile with yours
- faas-cli new --lang your-template your-ffmpeg
- edit your-ffmpeg.yaml to have correct FAAS URL, extra time params etc
- in your-ffmpeg folder make sure to have a handler.sh that look something like [this](https://github.com/alexellis/openfaas-streaming-templates/blob/master/ffmpeg/handler.sh). The handler.sh is where you pass your params to ffmpeg.